# Cpp integration tests

Tags: c++, unit-testing, integration-testing

I'm trying to learn a methodology or some design pattern for integration testing.
I'm not talking about unit testing or using mocks for unit testing.

I want to test some fetcher that involve several functions or some flow E2E.

Comment: Stack Overflow's not a very good place to start your research because such questions tend to be too open-ended to work in the Q&A format. It is a great place to fill in the blanks in your research or clarify points that are giving you problems.

Comment: It could be operating system specific. Perhaps use plugins (with [dlopen](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html)...) or generate test cases (e.g. with [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp)...). Take inspiration from [GNU autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/)

Comment: Take inspiration from the test suite of  [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/)... coded mostly in C++